# Web Service Throwing Error

Tags: c#, web-services, properties

I cannot figure this one out. This code has executed flawlessly for quite a while, now out of nowhere it fails. The web service it calls hasn't changed and I am kind of at a loss. The specific error is `{"Configuration system failed to initialize"}`

Code I'm using:

```
webservices.WebService ws = new webservices.WebService();
```

Code in the designer:

```
namespace NumberOneService.Properties {

[global::System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute()]
[global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editors.SettingsDesigner.SettingsSingleFileGenerator", "11.0.0.0")]
internal sealed partial class Settings : global::System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase {

    private static Settings defaultInstance = ((Settings)(global::System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase.Synchronized(new Settings())));

    public static Settings Default {
        get {
            return defaultInstance;
        }
    }

    [global::System.Configuration.ApplicationScopedSettingAttribute()]
    [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
    [global::System.Configuration.SpecialSettingAttribute(global::System.Configuration.SpecialSetting.WebServiceUrl)]
    [global::System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute("http://www.webserver.services/ws_partlookup.cfc")]
    public string Web_Service {
        get {
            return ((string)(this["Web_Service"]));
        }
    }
}
```

stack trace:

```
at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.OnConfigRemoved(Object sender, InternalConfigEventArgs e)
   at System.Configuration.Internal.InternalConfigRoot.RemoveConfigImpl(String configPath, BaseConfigurationRecord configRecord)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(String configKey, Boolean getLkg, Boolean checkPermission, Boolean getRuntimeObject, Boolean requestIsHere, Object& result, Object& resultRuntimeObject)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSection(String configKey)
   at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection(String sectionName)
   at System.Configuration.ClientSettingsStore.ReadSettings(String sectionName, Boolean isUserScoped)
   at System.Configuration.LocalFileSettingsProvider.GetPropertyValues(SettingsContext context, SettingsPropertyCollection properties)
   at System.Configuration.SettingsBase.GetPropertiesFromProvider(SettingsProvider provider)
   at System.Configuration.SettingsBase.GetPropertyValueByName(String propertyName)
   at System.Configuration.SettingsBase.get_Item(String propertyName)
   at System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase.GetPropertyValue(String propertyName)
   at System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase.get_Item(String propertyName)
   at NumberOneService.Properties.Settings.get_Web_Service() in Number One Service\Properties\Settings.Designer.cs:line 33
   at NumberOneService.webservices.WebService..ctor() in Number One Service\Web References\webservices\Reference.cs:line 46
   at NumberOneService.NumberOneService.bwExecuteProcess_DoWork(Object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) in Number One Service.cs:line 400
   at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.WorkerThreadStart(Object argument)
```

Answer (score 0):

This typically happens if you created a web service reference in a class library and then ported it over to a console app or a windows app. the web service references are stored in the settings files with a specific path.

Basically, you're missing a section declaration OR the right setting name in the config file.
please check your config files for the key which stores the url of the service. Else, paste it here and we can help further.

the exception is thrown in the web service constructor when it tries to set the Url from the config file. (host config or settings file)